# Controller has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber? Symfony 5

Tags: php, symfony, symfony5

I'm making my first application on Symfony 5

I ran into a problem when creating a controller, and I need a controller, not a service

**Uncaught PHP Exception LogicException: ""App\Controller\UploadFileController" has no container set, did you forget to define it as a service subscriber?" at /vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Controller/ControllerResolver.php line 36**

it is my simple Controller

```
class UploadFileController extends AbstractController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/test-upload", name="app_test_upload")
     */
    public function testAction(Request $request, FileUploader $fileUploader)
    {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

I tried to clean the cache, it didn't help

this is my services.yaml

```
services:
    App\Controller\UploadFileController:
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ['@service_container']]
```

Comment: If you extend `AbstractController` there's no need for explicitly declare the controller as a service. Maybe you're messing up with `services` definition (try to remove it from there)?

Comment: Did you post the whole **services.yaml** ? Do you still have [these lines](https://github.com/symfony/recipes/blob/main/symfony/framework-bundle/5.4/config/services.yaml#L10-L12) for autoconfiguration ?

Comment: @AymDev i delete this line, because i have the problem with autowire service and its argument

Comment: @Таня if you deleted the `autoconfigure` line I think that's what is causing your issue. This is probably what's setting up the controller as a service subscriber. Try putting it back maybe.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to add any releated information in your service.yaml file, you only need to edit your code in service.yaml file to be like that:

```
App\Controller\:
    resource: '../src/Controller/'
    tags: ['controller.service_arguments']
```